# Generate a secret key for JWT?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, jwt

Currently I have a hard-coded secret key I use for my JWT Token Generation.  What is the best way to generate this randomly when generating the token?  Also, what I don't understand is if the secret is randomly generated, how can it be that the secret would be randomly generated again for authentication purposes.  Am I missing something here or am I way off on how this works?  It appears that the secret key is not even random. Is it something I would store in web.config for example

Comment: Have you got the solution? I am having same question

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder - Not really... I just created put a static one in a config file

Answer (score 4):

Just expanding on @nodd13's post to I have used the following (in LinqPad) to randomly generate a key:

```
var key = new byte[32];
RNGCryptoServiceProvider.Create().GetBytes(key);
var base64Secret = Convert.ToBase64String(key);
// make safe for url
var urlEncoded = base64Secret.TrimEnd('=').Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');

urlEncoded.Dump();
```

This is indeed random and as I understand it you only need to do this once and you can then store this in your web.config to be referenced later.

Comment: Is it safe to be stored in the web.config for a web api 2 project?

Comment: Aren't the equal signs at the end of a base64-encoded string supposed to be there as part of the padding expected of base64 strings where the grouping of bits requires it?

Answer (score 2):

I used the following code from this  [blog post](http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/)

```
var key = new byte[32];
RNGCryptoServiceProvider.Create().GetBytes(key);
var base64Secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Encode(key);
```